# ForwardingSMTPAddress available with ms-graph?

Tags: azure, api, microsoft-graph-api, office365api

Trying to use MS Graph to retrieve ForwardingSMTPAddress of a mailbox.
Is this available?

Answer (score 0):

No, this isn't available at the moment.  What is the scenario you are considering?

Comment: This is part of a project where our organization is migrating from a local LDAP to AD on MS cloud.
I know power shell can achieve this, but would like to use the Graph API.
BTW, how about a mailbox's quota?